# Ubuntu 12.04 | Linux 3.13.6: Cannot connect to Ethernet, kernel modules are there but none are used

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I am trying to install a different version (3.13.6) of Linux kernel over my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (originally having kernel 3.2) for some research purposes. The problem is when I use my 3.2 kernel the Ethernet works fine and `lspci -v` shows Ethernet controller to have a kernel drive in use: r8168. When I reboot my system and boot the system with 3.13.6 kernel, I get stuck as **waiting for network configuration** thing. When the home screen comes I cannot log in to my account (because it need an internet access for logging in). Hence, I have to log in using the GUEST account which gives me no capabilities as a `sudo` user.

Secondly, when using my guest account I use `lspci -v` command, I see that the Ethernet controller has r8168 and r8169 modules available but none are being used as a driver. I have tried multiple things but the problem is I do not have internet access neither `sudo` access.

I get the `sudo` access and internet access when I log in using 3.2 kernel version. Is there any way I could something from my 3.2 linux kernel for my 3.13.6 kernel to resolve this issue?

These code snippets especially the LSPCI -V shows that my kernel 3.13.6 has driver modules available for the Ethernet controller but none are being used, as it should mention something like "kernel driver is use: _____":

> ================== LSPCI ================================

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1382 (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

> ================= LSCPI -V ====================================
>
> ## Showing just the Ethernet and Network Controller Description

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)  
Subsystem: Dell Device 05b7
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at f2100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: r8168, r8169

04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Device 0209
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Expansion ROM at f7180000 [disabled] [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: wl, ath9k
```

> ================== RFKILL LIST ALL ================================

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

The **wireless information** can be found [HERE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24376485/)

> =========== IFCONFIG ====================

Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited Output

Comment: I thought it would require SUDO permissions. Anyway Please help me out in this. My research is getting stalled because of this :(

Comment: `ifconfig` results in `cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied)`. Are you running this inside a (para-)virtualization container? What's the output of `id` and `ls -l /proc/net/dev`? Is this an Ubuntu Desktop or Server installation? Do you have NetworkManager (package `network-manager`) installed and enabled?

Comment: I am using a guest account as I cannot access my login account (which requires internet access).
"id" gives me "uid=136(guest-rJT0Ch) gid=144(guest-rJT0Ch) groups=144(guest-rJT0Ch)
"ls -l /proc/net/dev" gives me " -r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 13 17:51 /proc/net/dev"

Comment: I think it should be a server installation because all of us (research lab fellows) have an account to log into and our drives get mounted only if we get logged into our account using ethernet/WiFi

Comment: The guest account should have enough privileges for the parts of the diagnosis relevant to Ethernet adapters. It will also let you run the commands I asked you to run in my previous post and inspect installed packages and system configuration files.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: I ran the 'id' and 'ls -l /proc/net/dev' commands

Comment: If you don't have super-user privileges on the system in question 1) how did you install a different kernel and 2) how are you hoping to alter the system configuration in a meaningful way (i. e. to enable networking)?

Comment: When booted via kernel 3.2 I can access my account. When logged in, I have the ability to use sudo. Using that I installed this new kernel 3.13.6 when done with it, I rebooted the system. GRUB gave me the option to use kernel 3.13.6 and I got into it. Now when it comes to the home screen having the login information for all of us. I cannot use my account and log into it (because there is no internet connectivity). Thus I have to use a guest account.

Comment: You have a really weird system setup. `/proc/net/dev` is world-readable yet your (guest) account can't read it. I'm afraid there's no simple way to even diagnose the situation under these circumstances. It seems that the system in question is part of an institutional network and managed by some central authority (hence the account authentication via network), i. e. the local network administrators. I recommend that you contact them about this type of system configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I'll contact them and let you know about it.